# SQL to separate a group and add the values referring to them

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where it has its categories "P" - Pay, "R" - Receive, "C" - Credit and the categories have their values ... being in the following format

```
Money | Category
5         P
10        R
5         R
20        C
15        P
```

and get the result of my sql as

```
P  | R | C
20 | 15| 20
```

how to create a sql to generate these 3 columns without having to perform 3 subqueries?

```
select sum(money) from accounts -- that adds up all

select 
(select sum(money) from caixa where category= 'R' ) as 'CR',
(select sum(money) from caixa where category= 'P  ) as 'CP' 
from accounts -- this even works, but it returns me several lines with the same information
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: I am using the SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use *condition aggregate function* instead of subquery.

```
CREATE TABLE caixa (
   Money int,
   Categoty varchar(5)
);

insert into caixa  values (5,'P');
insert into caixa  values (10,'R');
insert into caixa  values (5,'R');
insert into caixa  values (20,'C');
insert into caixa  values (15,'P');
```

**Query**

```
select  sum(CASE WHEN Categoty = 'P' then money else 0 end) P, 
        sum(CASE WHEN Categoty = 'R' then money else 0 end) R, 
        sum(CASE WHEN Categoty = 'C' then money else 0 end) C
from caixa 
WHERE Categoty IN ('P','R','C')
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ddcd9241061dc17e39994788171ca00c)

Comment: Is this faster than making an equal query I did above?

Comment: I think that will faster than your query because it only search `accounts` table once. but it is base on you have create index.

Comment: You can add the condition in `where` I think it can let it faster.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option is a PIVOT

**Example**

```
Select * 
 From (
       Select [Money]
             ,[Category] 
         From Accounts 
      ) src
 Pivot ( sum([Money]) for [Category] in ([P],[R],[C]) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

```
P   R   C
20  15  20
```